# Solving ode with Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method

[image: question is here]

What i want to ask is both question 20 and 21 with Laplace transforms

Actually i can solve question 20 and 21 with method of undetermined coefficients but . In laplace transform, i don't know how to solve them 'efficiently'(especially 21, it can't be partial fraction expansion. So i dont know how to solve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 21 take a Laplace transform to obtain $$(s^2F(s)-s-1)+(sF(s)-1)+F(s)=\frac2{s^3}$$ which you can rearrange to obtain $$F(s)=\frac{s^4+2s^3+2}{s^5+s^4+s^3}$$

can you take it from here?

PS. See this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

---

Addendum

we have $$F(s)=\frac2{s^3}-\frac2{s^2}+\frac{s+\frac12}{s^2+s+1}+\frac72\frac1{s^2+s+1}$$

Comment: What you have done is exactly what i have done. I want to know how to find yp from there its denominator is quitely comlicating.

Comment: see the addendum.

Comment: I can transform first term and second term but in third term and fourth term, how can i transform with inverse laplace?

Comment: recall that Laplace of $e^{-ax}f(x)$ is $F(s+a)$. For the fist fraction recall the laplace of $\cos(Ax)$ and for the second that of $\sin(Ax)$. Note also that $s^2+s+1=(s+1/2)^2+3/4$ ...

Comment: Ohob i got it 1/({s+(1/2)}^2+3/4)

Answer (score 0):

For 20
$$F(s)=\frac{2 {{s}^{2}}+2 s-2}{{{s}^{6}}-3 {{s}^{5}}+3 {{s}^{4}}-{{s}^{3}}}=\frac{4}{s}+\frac{4}{{{s}^{2}}}+\frac{2}{{{s}^{3}}}-\frac{4}{s-1}+\frac{2}{{{\left( s-1\right) }^{3}}}.$$
$$y=x^2e^x-4e^x+x^4+4x+4$$

For 21
$$F(s)=\frac{{{s}^{4}}+2 {{s}^{3}}+2}{{{s}^{5}}+{{s}^{4}}+{{s}^{3}}}=\frac{s+4}{{{s}^{2}}+s+1}-\frac{2}{{{s}^{2}}}+\frac{2}{{{s}^{3}}}$$
$$y={{e}^{-\frac{x}{2}}}\, \left( \frac{7 \sin{\left( \frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right) }}{\sqrt{3}}+\cos{\left( \frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}\right) }\right) +{{x}^{2}}-2 x$$